# GtkFrame mystery: Different looks each time the program is started

Tags: linux, gtk, gnome, gtk2

This is really confusing the heck out of me. Take a look at this screenshot:

[image]

Sometimes, the `GtkFrames` in my program look like on the left side, and sometimes they look like on the right side - or even a mix of the two! The program is exactly the same. Just running the same program multiple times yields very different looks of the `GtkFrames` in the program! How can that be?

It seems that there are two different designs of `GtkFrame`:

1. The first one has its label centered at the top of the frame and
   smoothly dissolves towards the
   bottom so that the frame doesn't completely enclose the `GtkFrame`'s
   contents.
2. The second design has its label left-aligned at the top of the frame
   and draws a border around the complete `GtkFrame`.

The problem is now that GTK+ seems to choose one of the two designs entirely at random. I don't see any pattern in which design I'm going to get. It appears to happen completely at random which is really confusing me.

Can somebody shed a light onto this mystery? What is going on here? Is there a way to force GTK+ to use a certain design?

I'm using GTK+ 2.24.10 with the Adwaita theme on Linux Mint.

Comment: To clarify this is from wxwidgets and this isn't the Adwaita theme. See also: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2016-March/msg00027.html

Comment: @TingPing seems like oxygen-gtk bugs to me...

Comment: Yes, it is indeed oxygen-gtk. Sorry for reporting it as Adwaita. `gsettings` returned "Adwaita" but this information was nonsense because I'm using KDE and `gsettings` doesn't seem to provide reliable theme information in that case. So yes, it is the oxygen-gtk theme, not Adwaita.

Comment: Maybe there are two softwares that are competing on setting the current Gtk+ theme?